# How to use append/3 in Prolog to find the last 2 elements of a list

Tags: prolog

Using system predicate `append/3`, write predicates to return:

1. the last element of a list
2. the last 2 elements of a list
3. the last n elements of a list
4. the first n elements of a list.

thanks any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Have you played with `append/3` at the Prolog command prompt to see how it  behaves? What have you tried? Note that `length/2` can come in handy for #3 and #4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last element: `append(_, [X], List)`

Last two elements: `append(_, [X, Y], List)`

Last n elements: `length(LastN, N), append(_, LastN, List)`

First n elements: `length(FirstN, N), append(FirstN, _, List)`

Answer (score 2):

What does `append( A, B, C)` mean? It means

```erlang
 A=[..........]
           B=[.........]
 C=[...................]
```

What does

```erlang
     length( B, 2)
```

mean? It means

```erlang
            B = [X | B1           ],
            length(  B1, 1)
```

and so, that means

```erlang
            B = [X | B1           ],
                     B1 = [Y | B2],
            length(            B2,  0)
  % i.e.
            B = [X | B1           ],
                     B1 = [Y | B2],
                               B2 = []
  % i.e.
            B = [X | B1           ],
                     B1 = [Y | []]
  % i.e.
            B = [X |      [Y | []]]  = [X | [Y]]
              = [X ,       Y | [] ]
              = [X,        Y      ]
```

and so

```erlang
B = [X, Y], append( A, B, C)
```

means

```erlang
 A=[..........]
           B=[XY]
 C=[..........XY]
```

I think it is clear what it means. It means we can define

```erlang
one_before_last(C, X) :-
  % you can finish this up now!
```

And as we saw that `B = [_, _]` means `length( B, 2)` (i.e. we trace our equations in reverse), we can use other *things* as arguments to  `length`. To solve your *other* stated problems.

Comment: yes, finding the one before last element in the list was not among the stated problems. it's good to be able to solve even more problems, to master the issue.